# How to pass 'this' to prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this very simple test but it's throwing error:

```
Object.prototype.myMethod = function(this) { // How do I make 'this' work here?
  return this.toString();
};
```

and then I should be able to call it eg:

```
var str = 'This should be returned back';
str.myMethod(); // Expected output: This should be returned back
```

Comment: Home task: [Fully Understanding the this Keyword](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass `this` to the function. It's "just there" (couldn't find a better phrase to describe it). Calling the function like `str.myMethod()`, `str` becomes your "context", aka `this`, inside the function.

[Remove `this` from the parameter list](http://jsfiddle.net/gEcGT/).